# Weird behavior ionic in select, ng-model won't update

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

I'm experiencing something weird, this example works in codepen but won't work in my Ionic app.

When I change the option in the select tag I want to show the selected value, but it won't work, it shows `undefined`, i've tried in many ways.

This is not the original code, the original one retrieves the values from an external API and populates the options with ngOptions (which works, it populates ok). But it won't update the value in the controller.

So I decided to make it more simple, and it still won't work:

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="optionSelected" ng-change="selectUpdated()">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="h">Hello</option>
    <option value="b">Bye</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$scope.selectUpdated = function() {
    console.log('Updated');
    console.log($scope.optionSelected);
};
```

I don't think more code is needed, the HTML is contained in `ion-view` and `ion-content`. No errors are shown, only the 'Updated' output and `undefined`.

When changing the option, I get `undefined`. But this same code in codepen works just fine.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXvYmq

Can someone tell me what can be happening that triggers this odd behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution, pass the ngModel property as a parameter in the ngChange.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="optionSelected" ng-change="selectUpdated(optionSelected)">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="h">Hello</option>
    <option value="b">Bye</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.selectUpdated = function(optionSelected) {
    console.log('Updated');
    console.log(optionSelected);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem today and had to create a workaround to use the select normally.

javascript

```
$scope.updatePreferredLanguageValue = function() {
   $scope.PreferredLanguage = this.PreferredLanguage;
};
```

html

```
<select ng-model="PreferredLanguage" ng-options="Language.id as Language.name for Language in LanguageList" id="LanguageListSelect" name="LanguageListSelect" ng-change="updatePreferredLanguageValue()">
</select>
```

So basically I have a method that is called when the value is changed that makes sure the change is set on the $scope variable. Not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use $parent in your ng-model and call it from your controller.

**Example**

```
<select ng-model="$parent.selectedCar">
 <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes